# Read csv file and convert it to txt with custom formatting in Python

Tags: python, csv, append

I have been trying to do this for a bit but I need some direction. What I want to do secifically is to be able to read a a csv file (or excel...) in which we have table attributes. Take this attributes and add a "[" at the end of their names, after the "[" add column 1, then column 2 and so on...

IS this even possible? any help is much appreciated

Comment: Post what you've written so far...

Comment: put your expected sample output

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what you are asking. It looks you want something to look like the following: [Column1][Column2]...[ColumnN]

```
location = r'*Your CSV location'
reader = csv.reader(open(location), delimiter =',')
num_col = len(next(reader))
for row in reader:
for i in range(0, num_col):
    test = "[" + row[i] + "]"
    datalist.append(test)
print datalist
```

You can add additional text to your string with the + operator

Comment: Yeah basically I will have a csv file (or excel) and will want to process the tables with a python script that will generate an output similar to this:

REPORT1 for file1.csv
-------------------------------

COLUMN_1 [row_1
COLUMN_2 [row_2
COLUMN_3 [row_3
.
.
.
.
ENDREPORT[

The formatting and everything is essential, can this be done (real question) from a excel file, or does it have to be converted to csv?